# convert elasticsearch dsl queries to elasticsearch queries

Tags: python-3.x, elasticsearch

I am looking at a few elasticsearch dsl queries in python . Is there a way to convert them to elasticsearch queries that I can run using a tool like chrome elasticsearch-head.

Comment: u can use to_dict() method which converts the the actual query in json format which is used in Elasticsearch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With very few details you give, i can explain like this. In below query dsl code you can manipulate them with python variables as you see. So, in your case create a use-case with json and python variables similar like below.

```
body = {
    "query":
        {
            "bool": {
                "must": [
                    {
                        "term": {
                            "field1": {
                                "value": field1_variable
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "term": {
                            "field2": {
                                "value": field2_variable
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "range": {
                            "date_field": {
                                "lte": date_field_variable
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
    "aggs": {
        "date_field": {
            "max": {
                "field": "date_field"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Simply, create a json generator that works with user variables and turn it to dsl